# UE4 C++ Add PlatformTrigger Class

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Hi I was working on my UE4 C++ project and I noticed that I could not add

## include "PlatformTrigger.h" for my C++

So, I found out that my project does not have PlatformTrigger class.
Is there a way to add this class?

I guess this problem has occurred because I used a blank template for my project.

Furthermore, I cannot add these includes

## include "MenuSystem/MainMenu.h"

## include "MenuSystem/MenuWidget.h"

Comment: Do the files exist? Are they in the correct folders? If so, right click youre `.uproject` file and click `generate visual studio project files` and they should be added to your project. Make sure you close your engine before doing this.

Comment: No, the file does not exist (I cannot find with file name in VS)